# Rotate everything except UIImageView in Portrait/Landscape rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout, orientation

I have a UIImageView filling the whole screen as a background image and some buttons on top of it. When I rotate the screen, everything rotate but I wanted everything except this image. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no way to keep one item from rotating. But you can check when a rotation is about to occur/has just occurred. Once the rotation notification comes in, you could apply/remove a transformation on the image (depending on the new orientation).